# Google contact sync photo rotated

Tags: contacts, sync, samsung-galaxy-nexus, photos, profiles

I have enabled contact sync with my Google account on my Google Nexus phone running Android 4.1.2. One of my contacts' profile photo appears rotated to the left instead of being upright as set by the contact. The photo shows correctly when I view it on Google sites using the web browser on my laptop. What could be the issue and how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe your friend updated the photo but your phone hasn't yet synced.

Comment: I can see the updated photo in the correct direction on my laptop. But on the phone it appears rotated to the left. Could it be because the width was larger than the height that Contacts app automatically rotated it to fit it in portrait mode?